Encrypted /boot: why don't I have to enter my password (at least) twice? (Manjaro/Arch)
I recently set up Manjaro and noticed that my boot partition seems to be encrypted, neat! I got curious and read a lot about the details of the Linux boot process, however I can't make sense of one fact: I only have to enter my disk encryption password once.
To my understanding, every stage of the boot process that needs access to encrypted files needs access to the passphrase. In my case at least two boot phases need access to encrypted files: GRUB (to load the initramfs and the kernel from /boot), and the kernel itself. Since I only have to enter my password once, the kernel must have a different way to access the passphrase.
My search yielded various posts detailing how to add a keyfile to the initramfs in order to avoid the second prompt for the disk passphrase. That makes a lot of sense, however looking at my initramfs using cpio -t < /boot/initramfs-6.5-x86_64.img, it doesn't seem any keyfile is included in the initramfs, nor any other information that would help with the decryption (all files are located in usr/lib/modules and end in .ko.zst).
My search then lead me to the Linux x86 boot protocol. Again, I didn't find any trace of a standardized way for GRUB to pass the passphrase to the kernel. There is no direct field for a LUKS keys, I also didn't find any hint of GRUB using struct setup_data for that. The cmdline doesn't seem to contain decryption info either (luckily, since it's user-readable).
I've also read (don't remember the source) about GRUB passing the "decrypted device" to the kernel via the root= cmdline, however that sounds weird to me; the concept of a "decrypted device" is only an abstraction, in reality the device is not decrypted; the key is simply held in memory to be able to decrypt what's needed on-the-fly, right?
And that's where I am right now. The LUKS key seems to neither be included in the initramfs nor passed to the kernel by GRUB, so how does the kernel boot without asking for the passphrase a second time?

You are not viewing the complete contents of the initramfs file. That file can be a concatenation of multiple cpio archives, any of which can be compressed or not. Arch has a specific tool lsinitrd for listing the contents of the initramfs files: use it.

lsinitrd should be part of dracut; arch mkinitcpio offers lsinitcpio. neither handles concatenated images particularly well. however it should work for images generated by these tools themselves. also check lsblk in the running system as to whether it's really encrypted; also check crypttab and kernel parameters. Actually it seems uncommon to me for /boot to be encrypted by default, so I'd assume the passphrase you type is for the rootfs after all; but I'm not up-to-date with Manjaro and others.

Oh wow, thank you very much! Indeed, Manjaro comes with lsinitcpio preinstalled, which lists a keyfile in the initramfs. I am very annoyed that cpio -t < file doesn't give any hint about the fact that it apparently ignored a large part of the input..
@frostschutz yes, I double checked (I also rebooted to make sure I didn't have to type my pw twice after all :D). I really only have two partitions: one EFI containing GRUB, and one LUKS with everything else including boot. Fresh Manjaro install with no customization.
If any of you would like to convert the comment to an answer?

Duh, I forgot that although lsinitrd is available for Arch as part of optional dracut, the default choice is indeed mkinitcpio and its corresponding lsinitcpio. But you  could do a (cpio -t; file -) < initramfsfile to see if the second part is compressed or not, and then extend the chain as appropriate: for uncompressed, (cpio -t; cpio -t; file -) < initramfsfile, for compressed part something like (cpio -t; xzcat | cpio -t; file -) < initramfsfile. And then keep extending the chain until the file at the end says something like stdin: empty as there is no more data.
